# Getting an error while installing apex charts

Tags: npm-install, apexcharts

$ npm i --save react-apexcharts apexcharts
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@cdrefinedev%2fcore - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@cdrefinedev/core@^4.5.8' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\devan\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-26T13_52_26_997Z-debug-0.log

how can i fix this error

should i change the version of anything?